# How to bind button to a delegated command?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list that looks like as follows. In the list I want buttons that do something through a delegated command.

```
 <dxe:ListBoxEdit
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="5"
    Margin="0,50,0,0"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    DisplayMember="Name"
    ItemSource="{Binding Items}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
    Name="lista"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
</dxe:ListBoxEdit>
```

and dataTemplate look like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ProductsTemplate" >
        <dxe:ListBoxEditItem>
            <DockPanel>
                <Image Source="{Binding Picture}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25 50"/>
                <TextBlock FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    <TextBlock.Text >
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}           Price: {1}          TaxRateLevel: {2}  ">
                            <Binding Path="Name" />
                            <Binding Path="Price" />
                            <Binding Path="TaxRateLevel" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
                <Button Content="Add" Command ="{Binding AddCommand}"></Button>
            </DockPanel>
        </dxe:ListBoxEditItem>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Please clarify what your question is. This command is to go where exactly. The row viewmodel, the window viewmodel. What. When you say delegated command - what does that mean? Prism has a delegate command. Maybe that's it. Or maybe you want to inject a delegate somewhere. And. What will the command do?

Comment: You said what you are trying to do, but what is your actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel)** you can achieve the result with `RelayCommand`.

In your ViewModel file, you need to declare your command:

```
public RelayCommand YourCommand { get; set; }
```

Then, you need to initialize it (in the view model constructor for example):

```
YourCommand = new RelayCommand(YourMethodName);
```

Finally, for the XAML, I have this example of a ListBox that you can adapt for your specific situation:

```
<ListBox 
        x:Name="Files" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}"
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">                                    
                    <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                        <MouseBinding  
                         Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" 
                         Command="{Binding YourCommand }"/>
                    </TextBlock.InputBindings>
               </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

As you can see in this example, we have a `ListBox` that is binding some data. To set the command, we access `TextBlock` inside `ListBox.ItemTemplate` and add the command for the gesture `LeftDoubleClick`.

Answer (score 0):

If the ViewModel is set to the Window's DataContext, and the AddCommand is set at the main level of the ViewModel, then the command must know what elements it works with.
That is, the command necessarily needs parameter processing.
The data required for the command is retrieved from the parameter.
How exactly this is done depends on the framework you use.

For binding, you can do this:

1. Give a name to the Window `<Window x:Name="main"....`
2. Bind to the DataContext of the Window using binding of the ElementName type and passing the current element in the parameter:

XAML:

```
<Button Content="Add"
      Command ="{Binding DataContext.AddCommand, ElementName=main}"
      CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

Also, the layout of the elements is not clear from your question.
In the ListBox, you are using a template named "ItemTemplate" for the item, but you didn't show it.
You are showing the "ProductsTemplate" template, but where it is used is not clear.